# Why does my mac terminal command NOT work in a shell script?

Tags: linux, osx, shell

I have installed a linux version of fico xpress, which uses mosel as its binary executable. I can call mosel from any directory and execute a .mos model (along with argument passing) as follows:

```
mosel -c "exec PATH/TO/MODEL arg1='value1', arg2='value2'"
```

which finishes with exit code 0.

However, when I place the same text as above in a run.sh file and:

```
sh run.sh
```

I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libxprm_mc.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/xpress/bin/mosel
Reason: image not found
run.sh: line 4: 22768 Trace/BPT trap: 5       mosel -c "exec PATH/TO/MODEL arg1='value1', arg2='value2'"
```

I have searched for the dylib file, and it does not exist (as far as I can tell).
EDIT: I found the dylib file in `/usr/local/opt/xpress/lib`  Also of note, in order to run mosel from the command line I also had to set the following in `/etc/launchd.conf`:

```
setenv XPRESSDIR /usr/local/opt/xpress
setenv PATH $XPRESSDIR/bin:$PATH
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $XPRESSDIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
setenv CLASSPATH $XPRESSDIR/lib/xprs.jar:$CLASSPATH 
setenv CLASSPATH $XPRESSDIR/lib/xprb.jar:$CLASSPATH 
setenv CLASSPATH $XPRESSDIR/lib/xprm.jar:$XLASSPATH 
setenv XPRESS $XPRESSDIR/bin
```

Why am I getting this error from a shell script, but not from executing the same line in the terminal?

Comment: In your script try using `/usr/local/opt/xpress/bin/mosel -c ...`

Comment: Thanks, I tried your recommendation and I get the same result.

Comment: Where is the library `libxprm_mc.dylib` actually located? Is it in `/usr/local/opt/xpress/bin/mosel`?

Comment: It is in `/usr/local/opt/xpress/bin/lib`. Does the "Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/xpress/bin/mosel" mean that is where mosel is looking for `libxprm_mc.dylib`? Or does it mean that is where the script (i.e. mosel) that is looking for `libxprm_mc.dylib` is located?

Comment: When you run the command from the interactive shell (the command-line) it obviously knows where to find it by environment variables that are set most likely. When you run it as a script it's obviously not using them and can't seem to locate the dylib. There's a couple ways you can go about fixing it, one being `install_name_tool`, or adding it to `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You can see if it's set by doing `echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: I just noticed your edit, I think it's probably set in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, can you run this command from Terminal `echo "$XPRESSDIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"`

Comment: `echo "$XPRESSDIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"` returns: `/usr/local/opt/xpress/lib:`

Comment: I think that's it right there; try sourcing the `/etc/launchd.conf` in your script before the command (eg. `source /etc/launchd.conf`). You could also export the path if you wanted (eg. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/xpress/lib`).

Comment: Trying the `source` idea produces `setenv: command not found` errors, and then the same result as before.  And trying `export ...` also produces the same result as before. I'm sorry, I don't know much about shell scripting. I am trying to get this mosel command to work via python, which is giving the same error as the shell script. I believe that if I can solve the shell issue it will fix my python issue.

Comment: Yes, shell scripting is different than Python, I was thinking you were doing this solely in Bash.

Comment: I am doing it solely in Bash (in order to trouble shoot my larger issue). Why doesn't Bash see the system paths set in `launchd.conf`? Can it be fixed with `install_name_tool`?

Comment: Try doing it this way: `. /etc/launchd.conf` on the line above `mosel -c ...` in your script.

Comment: `. /etc/launchd.conf ` also produces `setenv: command not found` errors.

Comment: One more thing to try  `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/xpress/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, that is `env`, not `setenv`...

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and `env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` and I still get the same results (except now all of the `env` variables print to the console).

Comment: It really should've worked with what you tried. Where are you running the script from?

Comment: I am running it in terminal with `sh run.sh`. I have also tried `bash run.sh`. The directory is a sub folder of a project directory, one directory below the mosel model (.mos file that mosel executes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script try exporting the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable with the `dylib` path:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/xpress/bin/lib:${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}
mosel -c "exec PATH/TO/MODEL arg1='value1', arg2='value2'"
```

This should let the mosel executable know where the dynamic library is located.

Comment: Is there a permanent / system-wide way to fix this issue of the shell interpreter not seeing the same paths as the terminal? (In other words, is there a way to execute mosel in a shell script in the future without the `export` statement?)  I ask because not all users will have the same path to the xpress library - trying to keep my code portable :)